# Remove CRLF in large unix file, within a row

Tags: linux, unix, newline

The data file has 672 columns with tab as delimiter, CRLF is found at the end of each row and also within a row effectively splitting one row to multiple rows.

```
    ***Current***
    row1: col1<\t>col2<\t>col3<\t>col4<\r\n>
    row2: col1<\t>col2<\r\n>
          col3<\r\n>
          col4<\r\n>

    ***Expected***
    row1: col1<\t>col2<\t>col3<\t>col4<\r\n>
    row2: col1<\t>col2<\t>col3<\t>col4<\r\n>
```

Comment: On your sample, how to you can detect only 2 rows?

Comment: @user3089834: Not quiet sure what your are asking, that is just a sample of "current" and "end state". at unix I use head to sample the data in file.

Comment: With data have CRLF within a row as your sample, you cannot resolve your issue if you cannot detect the end of a row. With me, i see 4 rows on your sample data because i think "\r\n" is the end of a row.

Comment: I think this is a well defined problem. Unfortunately, its not one that is easily resolved with unix/linux line-oriented tools.Ideally, the solution is to go back to the source and fix it as you pull it from the source. There have been solutions to the problem posted here, but usually the writer uses odd terms, doesn't include a good example (as you have) and other obstacles to finding the answer. Hopefully, one of the people that have written answer will see this and help out. I would add a tag for `bash` and or `awk` to get a larger group of readers. Hover over your tags the #of flwrs. GoodL

Comment: If I understand the problem, you have 762 columns (with 671 `\t`) expected, but between some of the columns you have `\r\n` instead of `'t`. It seems, whether through shell, awk, or otherwise, you could read, noting the index for the column, from `1 - 671` and any found `\r\n` before `671` should be converted to a tab. Is that the problem we are here on?

Comment: do you have a constant number of columns?

Comment: Oops, you forgot to post your code! StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. Meta-code, even, will demonstrate how you're thinking a program should work, even if you don't know how to write it.

Comment: @shelter thankyou, hope to find a solution too.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin  the total number of columns in the file are 672 delimited by <tab> with \r\n at the end of each row. The issue is \r\n is also found within a row at random column numbers. you are right I need to parse each row replace the \r\n with a \t till I reach 672 columns, however, the tr and sed variations I have tried replace all the \r\n in the file, in effect it becomes a file with one big records :/

Comment: @ghoti noted, I will share the sed and tr variation I have tried, not very good at scripting though :I

Comment: @BalajiGA - looking forward to seeing your attempt. I have a simple solution in mind, but I'd like to see your work before posting it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script `reorder.sh` which when executed will create output file `expected.txt`

```
#!/bin/bash

input_file=$1;
j=1
for i in `awk '{for(k=1;k<=NF;++k) print $k}' $input_file`
do
        if [ $(( $j % 4 )) -eq 0 ]; then
                echo $i >> expected.txt
        else
                echo -n $i"     " >> expected.txt
        fi
        ((++j))
done
```

`./reorder.sh current.txt`

Answer (score 0):

The following sed script helped me to remove the CRLF character.

```
script.sed:join /\$/{N s/\\n// b join }
```

the method to call the above script

```
sed  -f  script.sed  chap4  > chap4.new
```